# Code to show message box if there is no data in table column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with 2 comboboxes.

Both comboboxes are populated from the tables present in the sheet.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Summary of Accounts")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("groupheads")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange

    Me.cmb1.Clear
    Me.cmb2.Clear

    With cmb1
        .AddItem "Debit"
        .AddItem "Credit"
    End With


    "If rng = vbNullString Then"
        MsgBox ("Please create the Group Head Account First")
    Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub
```

The error occurs at the quoted line as object variable not defined. What i want is if there is no data in the table column, the msg box should be appeared which I have shown in the above code.

Comment: Change this `If rng = vbNullString Then` to this `If rng.Rows.Count = 0 Then`

Comment: still the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a ListObject table has no data in the first row of the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) then setting a range type variable to it will result in Nothing.

```
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Please create the Group Head Account First")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Yes, it looks like there is an empty row there but the .DataBodyRange is actually nothing until it gets at least one value in one of the cells.

Comment: Yes it is. It is working now...But i have a small query that this code is put in userform initialization. What i need if certain criteria is met like above, it should also close the userform for that what should me done as i write unload me after msgbox but still userform is appearing...

Comment: I'm sorry but that sounds like a new question and too long to answer in a comment. There should also be plenty of similar questions in SO if you search. Post a new question if you cannot find an answer.